# Best way to restrict possible insert positions for a drag into a dropList

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I would like to be able to somehow limit at what positions a drag element can be dropped into a dropList. I couldn't find any way of doing that with the current API.

For example, for a dropList with 10 elements, a drag element can only be dropped between positions 3 and 7. Dragging over positions 1 and 2 shows the placeholder element on position 3, and drop event has position parameter set as 3. As a less desirable but still happy outcome, when dragging over positions 1 or 2, a placeholder is not shown, and the dropList does not fire the drop event when dropping there, as if the move were invalid.

I'm considering using a combination of CdkDragEnter and CdkDragMove to style the placehoder for invalid positions and then the drop event to cancel an invalid move, but maybe there's a better way of doing that?

I also considered using multiple droplists, but I need the whole area to be droppable, and with the long term goal of showing the placeholder on the previous valid index (as opposed to not showing a placeholder and not allowing the drop), a single dropList sounds a better approach to begin with.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Thank you.